# Xcode GIF output has color distorted when GIF has large amount of frames

Tags: ios, xcode, gif

I am creating a GIF in xcode using the following code:

```
NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:YES error:nil];
NSURL *fileURL = [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"animated.gif"];
CGImageDestinationRef destination = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)fileURL, kUTTypeGIF, imageArray.count, NULL);

NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:5];

NSDictionary *frameProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:dict forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyPNGDictionary];

NSMutableDictionary *dict2 = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:5];

const uint8_t colorTable2[9] = {0, 0, 0, 128, 128, 128, 255,255,255};
NSData *colorTableData2 = [NSData dataWithBytes:colorTable2 length:9];

[dict2 setObject:colorTableData2 forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyGIFImageColorMap];
[dict2 setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0] forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyGIFLoopCount];
[dict2 setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.005] forKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyGIFDelayTime];

NSDictionary *gifProperties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:dict2 forKey:(NSString *) kCGImagePropertyGIFDictionary];

for (int i = 0; i < imageArray.count; i++) {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[imageArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    CGImageDestinationAddImage(destination, image.CGImage, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)frameProperties);
}

CGImageDestinationSetProperties(destination, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)gifProperties);
CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination);
CFRelease(destination);
```

The issue here is that if the imageArray.count is lesser than 23, the output GIF will not contain color distortions. If it were greater than 22, color distortions will occur in the form of patches of the image taking the background color instead of their original color.

I do not think I have set any code to perform image compression so I am not sure why this is happening. If someone could provide some insight to this issue it will help me greatly.

edit:
I have saved each individual frame to ensure that the color distortions are not due to the frames themselves. Hence I feel it has to do with the CG Framework.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try using the ImageIO.framework framework for Using GIF in iOS APP, My GIF images where getting distorted too, but then I used this method and they were fine

```
NSURL *url1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"YourImage" withExtension:@"gif"];

self.imageView.image = [UIImage animatedImageWithAnimatedGIFData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url1]];
```

they came fine after This

Comment: Hi Geet, my issue is that the created GIF is already distorted. Up till "UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[imageArray objectAtIndex:i]];" everything is fine. As I can see the individually saved images are distortion free. But after "CGImageDestinationFinalize(destination);" the gif file is showing incorrect colors.

Comment: @Leon you ever find a solution for this?